# What is the equivalent of the 'gsettings' command on OS X?

Tags: terminal, command-line, settings

Under Ubuntu it's possible to get various settings information via `gsettings` command in terminal. For instance, current wallpaper path can be obtained via

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///home/jdoe/Pictures/wallpaper.png'
```

List of items on dock

```
$ gsettings get  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
['application://wps-office-et.desktop', 'application://wps-office-wpp.desktop', 'application://wps-office-wps.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
```

Is there something similar for OS X ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most approaching command line interface on MacOS X is the command `defaults`. All the settings are hierarchically structured inside `domains`, which are separated by dots (as in Ubuntu settings).

To get all the domains containing settings (the equivalent of `gsettings list-schemas`), enter:

```
defaults domains
```

and for a human readable version, enter:

```
defaults domains | sed -E 's/, /\
/g' | sort
```

Comment: @jonas-schulze: !